# gnome3, restore old behaviour for scroll bar

Tags: scrolling, gnome3

I am not sure when that changed, but now under gnome3.14, when i click the scrollbar background, instead of having a page up/down, the scroll handle moves to that location.

this is crazy and useless. how can anyone know what is on that point of the scroll bar? i can't see how that feature can ever be useful.

Is there any way to restore the previous, sane, page up/down behavior?

Answer (score 1):

As this [blog post](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2013/08/05/scrolling-in-gtk/) mentiones, your requested feature is now available by right click.
They changed the behavior in GTK+ 3.

Clicking outside the scroll thumb by left click (default behavior) now sets the thumb to the position to the mouse pointer and your content will scroll tho the proper position as well.

I agree with your opinion that this might be a more useless default behavior and to me it seems that the author of this post on the official Gnome Blog is not sure if it was the right desicion to change this as he starts the blog post with the following sentences:

> Scrollbars are hard to get right. They have very small click targets and are barely usable to make fine adjustments. In GTK+ 3, we’ve made a number of changes to scrollbars in the last few years.

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Comment: @DragonLord thanks for the lecture. I read through the Meta Stack Exchange post and updated my answer. I think it does now fit the needs.
Could you read through it as well and tell me your opinion?